# Make AngularJS ng-show and ng-hide safer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean

In AngularJS, I want to hide an element to restrict users that are not authenticated from seeing it.

ng-hide directive is working, but when someone is opening the Developer Tools, he can change the class given to the element (ng-hide) and then he can see the content.

How can I make ng-hide more secure for authorization?

Thank's for help!!!

**P.S: I'm using Node.JS for backend**

Comment: why don't use `ng-if`? it will remove the DOM if it isn't satisfy expression

Comment: replace `ng-show` by `ng-if`..

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` for example :

```
<input type='text' name='firstName' ng-if="expression" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by Pankaj Parkar, use ng-if. ng-if will remove elements from the DOM. ng-show/ng-hide does not remove the elements from the DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements.